# seeInField finds the element, while fillField doesn't - CodeCeption

Tags: php, unit-testing, acceptance-testing, codeception

I am totally new to CodeCeption. I have the below html inside the body,

```
<div><input type="text" name="content_id" id="contentId" maxlength="10" value="123"></div>
```

In CodeCeption acceptance test I have a this below code

```
`<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('fillfield test');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->seeInField('#contentId', 123);
$I->fillField('#contentId', 222397);
?>`
```

seeInField Test passes successfully, but fillField throws an error

**Sorry, I couldn't fill field "#contentId", 222397 

InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty**

This stops me to proceed further. Help me out on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally got answer to my own question. I used PhpBrowser module for testing, it won't allow the user to fill fields which are not inside the form. And other stuffs they mentioned in the Docs are,

**Common PhpBrowser drawbacks:**

1. You can click only on links with valid urls or form submit
   buttons
2. You can't fill fields that are not inside a form
3. You can't work with JavaScript interactions: modal windows, datepickers, etc.,

Comment: What was your solution to using Codeception for JS interactions?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to fill input fields without a form.