# Codeception with Webdriver $I->fillField not working although the field is seen

Tags: php, ajax, selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

Being pretty new to Codeception I am having a problem with the following code:

```
$I->click("a.slideout-toggle-add-employee");
$I->wait(2);
$I->seeElement(Locator::find('input', ['placeholder' => 'Vorname']));
$I->fillField(Locator::find('input', ['placeholder' => 'Vorname']),"Testerina");
$I->wait(2);
```

The output when running `codecept run` is like this:

```
 I click "a.slideout-toggle-add-employee"
 I wait 2
 I see element "//input[@placeholder = 'Vorname']"
 I fill field "//input[@placeholder = 'Vorname']","Testerina"
  Screenshot and page source were saved into '...' dir
 ERROR
```

In my setup I am using selenium-standalone and the following configuration:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver:
        url: 'http://localhost:19080/'
        browser: chrome
        host: '127.0.0.1'
        port: 4444
        restart: false
        window_size: 1920x1080
    - \Helper\Acceptance
    - Asserts
```

In a similar question I have read that fillField can be a problem with PhpBrowser but this does not answer my question: [seeInField finds the element, while fillField doesn't - CodeCeption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349463/seeinfield-finds-the-element-while-fillfield-doesnt-codeception)

The is probably delivered via ajax within the page but as the element is found with the locator I do not understand what is wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer - there was some unknown hidden element which matched the same selector and this element caused an Exception:

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotInteractableException] element not interactable.

I found out using the `grabMultiple` function:

`print_r($I->grabMultiple(Locator::find('input', ['placeholder' => 'Vorname'])));`

The solution was to use a more specific selector:

`$I->fillField('.employees-list input[name="user_firstname"]',"Testerina");`